# require() not working in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, require, directory-structure

I am using the basic Laravel 5 file structure.

I basically have some .php files inside of the app directory. I am trying to call them from a controller within the app/Http/Controllers directory.

```
require ('../../PlaylistRetrieval.php');
require ('../../Playlist.php');
```

These are the two lines that are failing from within my controller. My IDE, PhpStorm, shows that it recognizes the directories. However it is throwing a FatalErrorException.

Here's a photo of the file structure. Incase you aren't familiar with Laravel 5. The require functions above are being called from within `PlaylistController.php`.

[image]

I am still rather new to the PHP and Laravel world, so if it's something simple I apologize.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of the require function, you could make use of namespaces. Assuming you have some model files for your Controller:

```
use App\Playlist;
use App\PlaylistRetrieval;
```

If you have your own classes, you could put them in your own folder app/Libraries and use them with (example with 'Libraries'):

```
use App\Libraries\Playlist;
```

and within your Controller:

```
$play = Playlist::find(1);
```

or directly:

```
$play = App\Libraries\Playlist::find(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
require (__DIR__.'/../../PlaylistRetrieval.php');
require (__DIR__.'/../../Playlist.php');
```

Or if this ones are the classes then you should namespace them in App namespace then like the answer below says use

```
use App/Playlist;
```

Comment: why is this rated so badly? +1 for the __DIR__ it worked instantly for me.